# How to explode a Spark DataFrame (sql) and iterate through Rows in JAVA 8

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to replicate in Java something quite easy to achieve in Scala. To explode a Spark DataFrame and iterate through rows in order to apply logic (and return the rows modified)

Scala version example (working case)

```
case class someModel(A: String, B: String)
someDF.explode(someDF("A"), someDF("B")) {
      case Row(A: String, B: String) =>

          List(someModel("a value", "a second value"))

    }
```

Java version (how far I've reached, not working)

```
someDF.explode(columnsToExplodeSeq, new Function1<Row, TraversableOnce<Row>>() {
            @Override
            public TraversableOnce<Row> apply(Row v1) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public <A> Function1<A, TraversableOnce<Row>> compose(Function1<A, Row> g) {
                return super.compose(g); // this give compile error, not calling super method!
            }

            @Override
            public <A> Function1<Row, A> andThen(Function1<TraversableOnce<Row>, A> g) {
                return super.andThen(g); // this give compile error, not calling super method!
            }
});
```

Comment: which version of java? if you have java8, then you can do something like columnsToExplodeSeq.stream().map( a -> function(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Java 8
The example you just posted is in Scala. I have a Scala version working, where a complex process happens inside the "case Row() => ..." block - the one I posted is just something simple which I would like to translate into Java.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my example is in java.. since java 8, you can write a concise code in java too ;) java 8 supports lamba expressions too

Comment: is stream() a DataFrame function ? It seems not